# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los resultados de una consulta MySQL en un arreglo en C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Realizo diferentes consultas en MySQL, pero utilizo la palabra reservada `UNION` para unir cada consulta y lo que quiero es obtener todos lo resultados que me devuelven esos `select` unidos desde C#

```
SELECT AVG(CatTarifas.Valor) from CatTar WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(`Fecha`, '%d/%m/%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('01/06/2019', '%d/%m/%Y')) AND(DivTar LIKE '%valle de mexico sur%') AND (Tarifa = 'GDMTH') AND(Concepto = 'Base') UNION
SELECT AVG(CatTar.Valor) from CatTar WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(`Fecha`, '%d/%m/%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('01/06/2019', '%d/%m/%Y')) AND(DivisionTarifa LIKE '%val%') AND (Tar = 'G') AND(Concepto = 'Int') UNION
SELECT AVG(CatTar.Valor) from CatTar WHERE (STR_TO_DATE(`Fecha`, '%d/%m/%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('01/06/2019', '%d/%m/%Y')) AND(DivTar LIKE '%val%') AND (Tar = 'GD') AND(Concepto = 'Pun')
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ayudarte mas ocupo los nombres de la columna pero por el momento intentare darte un ejemplo rapido de como se debe hacer.
1) Generamos una clase en la cual deberían coincidir las columnas.

```
public class ClassName
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public int Col2 { get; set; }
}
```

2)Generamos el metodo en c# desde la parte que quieras puede ser un static para que no tenga que estar ligado a ninguna clase, desde el cual declaramos la sentencia y este la corre y linea por linea las va añadir a la lista esa parte del código quedaría así:

```
ClassName[] allRecords = null;
string sql = @"SELECT col1,col2
               FROM  some table"; // Aqui va tu sentencia.
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var list = new List<ClassName>();
        while (reader.Read())
            list.Add(new ClassName { Col1 = reader.GetString(0), Col2 = reader.GetInt32(1) }); // cambia los col por los nombres de tu columna. Este metodo utiliza una forma array para traer los datos.
        allRecords = list.ToArray();
    }
}
```